Pass the date value to the form field (Calendar)
I have a booking widget. It has a “Date” field (calendar), which is also implemented using flatpickr, and a “Book” button.
I also have a modal window in which a WPFORMS form with a “Date” field (calendar).
I need that when the user selects a date in the widget and clicks “Book” – this date enters the WPFORMS form in the “Date” field, and this date must also be selected on this calendar.
The problem is that the required date should be selected in the calendar of the form. How to do it?
        const bookWidget = document.getElementById('widget-booking-hotel')

    const fDateInInput = bookForm?.querySelector('.book-date-in input')
    const fDateOutInput = bookForm?.querySelector('.book-date-out input')
    const fGuestsSelect = bookForm?.querySelector('.book-guests select')

    if (bookWidget) {
        const dateInputs = bookWidget.querySelectorAll('.datepicker')
        const select = bookWidget.querySelector('.select-choices')

        // DatePicker
        if (dateInputs.length > 0) {
            const paramsIn = {
                locale: "uk",
                dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
                minDate: "today",
                onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    if (fDateInInput && instance.input.id == 'book-date-in') {
                        fDateInInput.value = dateStr;

                        const selectedDate = selectedDates[0];

                        if (selectedDate && flatpickrInstanceOut) {
                            flatpickrInstanceOut.set("minDate", selectedDate);
                        }
                    }
                },
            };

            const paramsOut = {
                locale: "uk",
                dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
                minDate: "today",
                onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    if (fDateOutInput && instance.input.id == 'book-date-out') {
                        fDateOutInput.value = dateStr;
                    }
                },
            };

            const flatpickrInstanceIn = flatpickr("#book-date-in", paramsIn);
            const flatpickrInstanceOut = flatpickr("#book-date-out", paramsOut);
        }
}


In your recently deleted question, make sure you move the event listener OUTSIDE any code that can be called more than once. and delegate from the closest static container
